# An example of parallel programming with multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

So I think I understand the overview concept of parallel programming and multithreading, but I was wondering if you can achieve multi-process multi-threaded applications.  If that makes sense, when looking at some of the descriptions of multi-threading it can be run on one processor but if you can process on multiple cores using parallel can you also multi-thread on multiple cores? If you can, could someone show me a simple example of this, using a `for loop` maybe?

Multi-threaded example:

```
public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Counter foo = new Counter();
        ThreadStart job = new ThreadStart(foo.Count);
        Thread thread = new Thread(job);
        thread.Start();

        for (int i=0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Main thread: {0}", i);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}

public class Counter
{
    public void Count()
    {
        for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Other thread: {0}", i);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
}
```

Example of parallel:

```
int n = ...
Parallel.For(0, n, i =>
{
   // ... 
});
```

Comment: Isn't Parallel.For just a shortcut to spawning threads for that loop?

Comment: There are a lot of examples of this you can find, both here and searching online.  For example, my series: http://reedcopsey.com/series/parallelism-in-net4/ is easy to find for C# threading...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distribution of tasks to available logical CPUs is the task of the operating system.  If you write a multithreaded application the OS will manage distributing the various threads to the hardware processors in the system.  There is nothing you have to do as a programmer to make this happen.

You can, however, manage this directly - associating a specific thread to run on a specific core or subset of logical processors, but generally this is less efficient than allowing the OS to manage hardware allocation since it has broader awareness of all processes running on the system and in most all cases handles the allocation in the most efficient way.

In brief, if your application is multithreaded then it *will* run on as many available cores as the system provides.

Comment: Should I bother to learn about parallel then, within the context of C# development?

Comment: @KirstyWhite `Parallel.For` is a built-in shorthand in .NET that relieves the programmer of the need to explicitly create worker threads or make use of the .NET threadpool.  While in the context of a single thread, `Parallel.For` will spin out the loop, executing the iterations in parallel on the threadpool rather than in sequence on the calling thread.  This carries the restriction that the loop must be threadsafe and must be mutually independent (ie:doesn't depend on the results from previous iterations).  It's an easy way to thread the loop without explicitly making new threads.

Comment: @KirstyWhite you should certainly learn about it, in any case - whether you decide to use it for any given problem depends more on the complexity and nature of the algorithm at hand.  In some cases `Parallel.For` is a great way to speed up a loop, in others, where the app may already be heavily multithreaded, it may be better to subdivide larger tasks across threads.  It really depends on what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Maybe that is where im confused, I thought Parallel.for was telling it to use multiple cores not just another way of multi-threading. I need to go learn more on the differences in parallel programming vs multi-threading.

Comment: @KirstyWhite yes, it's all just a different means to the same end. Threads are parallel by nature.  One thread can only do one thing at a time and can only run on one core at a time.  All running threads, however, will make use of whatever cores are available on the system, no matter what method you use to create them, either as explicit new threads, as tasks given to the threadpool, or via something like `Parallel.For`.

Comment: Thank you J, I assume tho that I should be looking at parallel rather than multithreading in so far as to want a faster more efficient programme? I get the impression multi-threading is an older way of doing things in .NET? Just not sure where to start.

Comment: @KirstyWhite no, multi-threading is very much a proper way to do things.  As I said, it very much depends on the task at hand.  `Parallel.For` is suitable for small, contained tasks.  It is newer, to be sure, and represents an easier way to thread small tasks, but it is by no means a replacement for heavier-duty multithreading in the context of a larger or more complex application.  It's just a different tool in the toolbox, so to speak.  Sometimes you need a screwdriver, sometimes you need a jackhammer.  It depends on what you are doing.  Suggest you read Reed's link above.